# PHP mail() sends empty variables

Tags: php, arrays, email

I have a validation class that outputs an array ($arr) `$validates = Comment::validate($arr);` I use the array for PHP's mail function: `$email=$arr['email'];  $name=$arr['name']; $message=$arr['comment'];`.
The mail gets send without problems, but the script behaves is if the variables were empty, but they are not (I have tested it with an `echo` statement). However `$name=$_POST['name'];` etc. works just fine. Any suggestions why this is happening? Here is part of the code.

```
$validates = Comment::validate($arr); // validate and fetch data, can be either TRUE or FALSE (1 or 0)


// ------------- CONFIGURABLE SECTION ------------------------
$mailto = 'email@bla.de'; // set to the email address you want the form sent to
$subject = "Feedback Form"; // $subject - set to the Subject line of the email
$formurl = "feedback.html" ;
$errorurl = "feedback_error.php" ;
$thankyouurl = "feedback_thankyou.php" ;
$uself = 0;
$email = $arr['email'];
$name = $arr['name'];
$message = $arr['comment'];
// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70, "\r\n"); // \n Line Feed, \r Carriage Return

$headers   = array();
$headers[] = "MIME-Version: 1.0";
$headers[] = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1";
$headers[] = "From: Sender Name <sender@domain.com>";
$headers[] = "Bcc: JJ Chong <bcc@domain2.com>";
$headers[] = "Reply-To: Recipient Name <receiver@domain3.com>";
$headers[] = "Subject: {$subject}";
$headers[] = "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion();


// -------------------- END OF CONFIGURABLE SECTION ---------------

$http_referrer = getenv( "HTTP_REFERER" );
$js_enabled = $_POST['js_enabled'];

//--------------------------------------------------------
if($validates) {
//echo 'message: '.$message; <-- this works (it's not empty)

$msg = array();
$msg[] = "Nachricht von: ".$http_referrer;
$msg[] = "Name des Absenders: ".$name;
$msg[] = "E-Mail des Absenders: ".$email;
$msg[] = "------------------------- Nachricht -------------------------";
$msg[] = $message; // <-- this is not working ??? ($message=$_POST['comment']; works just fine)
$msg[] = "--------------------------------------------------------------";

mail($mailto, $subject, implode("\r\n",$msg), implode("\r\n",$headers));


// THANK YOU URL 
if ($js_enabled == '0') { // IF NO jAVASCRIPT
    header("Location: $thankyouurl"); 
    exit; 
} // ELSE AJAX REQUEST
echo json_encode(array('status'=>1));
// echo '{"status":1}';
} else { // ERROR URL 
    if ($js_enabled == '0') { // IF NO jAVASCRIPT 
        $err = serialize($arr);
        $err_url = urlencode($err);
        header("Location: $errorurl?errors=$err_url"); exit; 
    } // ELSE AJAX REQUEST
    echo '{"status":0,"errors":'.json_encode($arr).'}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever initialize `$arr`? It looks like you are expecting it to be identical to `$_POST`, but I don't see a reference to `$_POST` in your code.

Comment: Yes, I did. There are $_POST references for name, email etc. within my Comments Class (which I did not post), i.e. if(!($data['name'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST,'name',FILTER_CALLBACK,array('options'=>'Comment::validate_text')))&& $name_required ) {
   $errors['name'] = 'No name!';
  }

Comment: Okay, but how do you initialize `$arr`?  Unless `Comment::validate($arr);` (1) accepts its parameter by reference and (2) modifies the input, `$arr` is not getting initialized by what you have posted here.  Do a `var_dump[$arr]` and see what you get.

Comment: Yes I did, right after `if($validates) {` in my code above I tested `$message`. With your `var_dump($arr)` I get `array(5) { ["email"]=> string(10) "web@wee.de" ["url"]=> string(0) "" ["comment"]=> string(12) "test message" ["name"]=> string(3) "mr." ["your_message"]=> string(0) "" }`. I had something similar working before, but don't know what's different this time.

Comment: When I do this online I get `message:
array(5) { ["email"]=> string(0) "" ["url"]=> bool(false) ["comment"]=> bool(false) ["name"]=> bool(false) ["your_message"]=> bool(false) } `

Comment: I think it's because of `mysql_real_escape_string` of the $POST values within my validation Class. It's this line: `// If the data is valid, sanitize all the data and copy it to $arr: foreach($data as $k => $v) {$arr[$k] = mysql_real_escape_string($v); }` But it used to work before. Dunno why it's causing this error now. there must be a way to real_escape these values without causing these boolean errors.

Comment: I just read, that "A MySQL connection is required before using mysql_real_escape_string(), otherwise FALSE is returned." If I am not mistaken, this might have been the cause for all the bool(false) values in $arr.

Comment: That's almost certainly your problem.